# Can i set up a 7speed gear and disc brake on hercules rocky mtb 2.0 cycle

Tags: gears, disc-brake

[image: this is my cycle]My cycle is a non gear cycle .Can i set up disc brake and 7speed gear.

[![ this is my cycle ][2]][2]

Comment: I searched for ["disk brake conversion"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=disk+brake+conversion) and found a number of useful answers. Without a lot more information about what exactly your bike is, and what you want to do, we can't really help you except by suggesting you use the search function and [read the introduction to bicycles.SE page](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: So, Non-gear cycle == singlespeed or fixed gear bike, and it likely has no other rear brake.   It would be ludicrously expensive to change, you should buy a bike set up as you want it.

Comment: I've googled and found the above image.  That bike lacks any deraileur hanger fitting, so your only option would be an internally geared hub built into the back wheel.  If that image is wrong please use revert to undo the edit.

Comment: The bike costs about 4000 rupees, or $AU80. And note the caliper brakes. It looks like a BSO, it's priced like a BSO... it's probably not worth what it costs new.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

There are two main problems:

1. Your bike does not have disc brake tabs.
2. Your bike does not have a derailleur hanger.

To be fair, it *could* be done, it would just be so expensive that you'd be better off buying a completely new bike with gears and disc brakes. If you chose to pursue this project, you would need:

- a new fork with disc brake tabs (with the type of fork you have, this might actually be pretty hard to find)
- some sort of disc brake conversion kit for the rear (I know that these have been made in the past, but they may be hard to find now. I'm also not sure that I, personally, would trust something as important as braking to a conversion kit.)
- A new set of wheels with disc compatible hubs and an internally geared rear hub.
- disc brake rotors
- disc brake calipers
- A gear shifter that's compatible with whatever internally geared hub you decide to buy
- a derailleur cable
- new brake cables

And I'm sure it goes without saying that you'll need some tools and a good book about bicycle maintenance.

I think that covers it. You're probably looking at $500 (US) minimum, probably more like $1000.

For that price, just buy a new bike that has discs and gears.